# Creating Snapshoot Gallery From Video

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

Anyone know of an application for creating a snapshot gallery from a video file, like this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the standard Gnome video player Totem.
From the [Totem manual](http://library.gnome.org/users/totem/unstable/totem-usage.html.en#totem-usage-create-screenshot-gallery):

> ## 3.14. To Create a Screenshot Gallery
>
> To create a gallery of screenshots of the movie or visualization that is playing,
>   choose **Edit ▸ Create Screenshot Gallery**. The *Save Gallery* dialog is displayed. Choose a location and insert the filename as which you want to save the gallery image, then click on the **Save** button to save the screenshot.
>
> You may specify the width of the individual screenshots in the gallery using the **Screenshot width** entry. The default width is 128 pixels.
>   You may also specify the number of screenshots to be put in the gallery. By default, this is calculated based on the length of the movie; however, this may be overridden by deselecting the **Calculate the number of screenshots** checkbox and entering the new number in the **Number of screenshots** spin box.

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly use it from the command line with the `totem-video-thumbnailer` command.